# Grails: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method clearTime() on null object

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Here is the code that should fatch all the students:

```
List<Student> getStudentListByCriteria(){
    List<Student> studentList= Student.list()
    return studentList
}
```

When I run the application it throws an exception saying...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method clearTime() on null object
```

Comment: Put your Student class code because problem is probably inside list() method

Comment: Could you please post full stack trace?